# Show $\int_{0}^{1} \sin(x+\frac{1}{x})dx$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Show $\int_{0}^{1} \sin(x+\frac{1}{x})dx$ converges.

Through $y=1/x$ subistitution we have $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{y^2}\sin(y+\frac{1}{y})dy$.  From here I'm not sure what could be done.  Also is it possible to *evaluate* such an integral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^2}dy$ converges and $|\frac{1}{y^2}\sin(y+\frac{1}{y})| \le \frac{1}{y^2}$ for $y\in [1,\infty)$, $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{y^2}\sin\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)dy$ converges absolutely by the comparison test. According to [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin(x%2B1%2Fx)+from+0+to+1),
$$
\int_0^1 \sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)dx \approx 0.3762
$$

Comment: Also doesn't the comparison test require that $\frac{1}{y^2}sin(y+\frac{1}{y})$ is always positive?

Comment: @helios321 $\sin(y+\frac{1}{y})/y^2$ is not always nonnegative. However, $|\sin(y+\frac{1}{y})/y^2|$ is always nonnegative. Thus I explained that the integral converges **absolutely**.

Comment: I have another small question, there is another answer below by "Fred" which uses the same comparison test directly on the original integral without substitution.   Is that method valid?

Answer (score 3):

Convergence: Since $ \int_0^1 1 dx$ converges and $|\sin(x+1/x)| \le 1$, the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \sin(x+\frac{1}{x})dx$ converges absolutely by the comparison test.

Comment: I thought the comparison test was used only for taking integrals to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use the fact that the integrand has modulus $\le 1$. The behaviour at one point, $x=0$, doesn't change the integral.

Comment: what do you mean by modulus

Comment: @helios321 The modulus of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is $|x|:=\max\{x,\,-x\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is continuous and bounded between $-1$ and $1$ on the interval $(0,1)$, hence the given integral is trivially convergent

By enforcing the substitution $x+\frac{1}{x}\mapsto z$ we have

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(x+\tfrac{1}{x}\right)\,dx &=& \frac{1}{2}\int_{2}^{+\infty}\sin(z)\left[\tfrac{z}{\sqrt{z^2-4}}-1\right]\,dz\\&=&\int_{1}^{+\infty}\sin(2u)\left[\tfrac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}-1\right]\,du\\&=&\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2u)}{(u+\sqrt{u^2-1})\sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2v+2)}{(v+1+\sqrt{v^2+2v})\sqrt{v^2+2v}}\,dv\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the last integral is clearly convergent by the Dirichlet test, since $\sin(2v+2)$ has a bounded primitive and $(v+1+\sqrt{v^2+2v})\sqrt{v^2+2v}$ is an increasing and unbounded function behaving like $\sqrt{2v}$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin. To apply the (inverse) Laplace transform to the last integral is a god way for deriving accurate numerical approximations, like $\color{blue}{0.37619956866}$.